# Return a growing number based on another number in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I want to make a function taking one number argument that returns:

- `4` for `0.1`
- `8` for `1`
- etc... it should return a valid number following that pattern no matter what number is passed, though the number is typically expected to be a float between `0` and `1`

I don't know the proper term to call this kind of operation.
I can only come up with a function like `num => 4 + 4 * num`, but that is incorrect since passing `0.1` returns `4.4`.

Comment: Add some more expected output.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please add your initial findings, along with code

Comment: so, if 4 for 0.1 and 8 for 1 would 16 for 10?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with a clear problem statement

Comment: An FYI, considering the last statement e.g. num => 4 + 4 * num

If you pass in 0.1, the multiplication will be considered before the addition, hence the result of 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the logarithm of ten and some adjustments.

```js
const f = x => x && 8 / (1 - Math.log10(x));

console.log(f(0.001)); // 2
console.log(f(0.1));   // 4
console.log(f(1));     // 8
```

Or slightly different

```js
const f = x => x && 8 / (1 + Math.log10(1 / x));

console.log(f(0.001)); // 2
console.log(f(0.1));   // 4
console.log(f(1));     // 8
```